# Change a channel receiver type from Receiver<T> to Receiver<U>

Tags: rust, channel

I've got an interface, which defines a method that returns a receiver:

```rs
pub fn subscribe(to: &str) -> crossbeam_channel::Receiver<Message>;
```

I am using a library method that returns a Receiver, but of a different message type:

```
pub fn subscribe(to: &str) -> crossbeam_channel::Receiver<lib::Message>;
```

It is easy enough to convert `lib::Message` to `Message` but how could I implement the interface, which would act as a wrapper for this library, such that the type returned is correct?

I've tried to create a new channel, but this doesn't work, (I think) since the method will return and then no longer pass messages to the new channel, therefore the `receiver` will always be empty.

```
let sub_recv = subscription.receiver();
let (send, receiver) = crossbeam_channel::unbounded::<Message>();
for m in sub_recv.try_recv() {
    send.send(m.into()).map_err(|_| MQError::ConversionError)?;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Uhm, why don't convert at the point of consuming the value?

Comment: The problem is that `crossbeam_channel::Receiver` is not an interface, but a concrete type. So yes, if you get an actual receiver, you will indeed need to create another sender/receiver pair. The part your code is missing is a background thread that will drain the original receiver and convert and stuff it to the sender. Also note that you almost certainly don't want the intermediate channel to be unbounded because it will fail to provide backpressure if the consumer is slower than the producer.

Comment: @Netwave not sure what you mean. If it's an interface, and I potentially want to change out the implementation behind that interface, than I'd have to change the consumer? Why even use an interface at that point.

Comment: @user4815162342 Yeah, the background thread was a solution, but I thought there might be a cleaner way to do it than that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert between your types you should run background task to do so, because otwerwise you would block the thread where you are trying to do so.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7184de4813796b8a2bf83e4c19fa6d78)

```rust
use crossbeam_channel::{Receiver, unbounded}; // 0.5.0

trait ReceiverCompatExt<T>
{
    fn convert(self) -> Receiver<T>;
}

impl<T, U> ReceiverCompatExt<U> for Receiver<T>
    where U: From<T>,
          T: Send + 'static,
          U: Send + 'static,
{
    fn convert(self) -> Receiver<U> {
        let (sender, receiver) = unbounded();
        
        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            while let Ok(value) = self.recv() {
                if sender.send(value.into()).is_err() {
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        
        receiver
    }
}
```